# Check an own API with maven animal sniffer plugin

Tags: java, maven, animal-sniffer

I want to use the animal sniffer to check a class against my own API, which contains just one class and one method:

```
package sniffertestapi;

public class MainInterface
{
    public static void testMethod(String testString)
    {
        System.out.println(testString);
    }
}
```

The following simple POM is used to build the project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>TestAPI</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestAPI</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>animal-sniffer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.13</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <javaHome>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51</javaHome>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The build runs fine, it installs TestAPI-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.signature and jar into my maven repository.

Next I want to add TestAPI as a dependency and use the `testMethod` from another project.

```
package sniffertest;

import sniffertestapi.MainInterface;

public class Tester
{
    public Tester()
    {
        MainInterface.testMethod("Hi");
    }
}
```

In this project I added the animal sniffer plugin with another goal:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>TestTester</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestTester</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>animal-sniffer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.13</version>
                <configuration>
                    <signature>
                        <groupId>TestAPI</groupId>
                        <artifactId>TestAPI</artifactId>
                        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    </signature>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>TestAPI</groupId>
            <artifactId>TestAPI</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This build runs of course with success also. Now I change the `testMethod` to have two parameters:

```
public static void testMethod(String testString, String testString2)
{
    System.out.println(testString);
}
```

And use it from the second project:

```
    MainInterface.testMethod("Hell", "o");
```

This time I expect the build for the second project to fail, because signature have changed. It differs from that one saved in signatures-file. But the build results in success and animal-sniffer-plugin outputs only these two lines:

```
[INFO] --- animal-sniffer-maven-plugin:1.13:check (default) @ TestTester ---
[INFO] Checking unresolved references to TestAPI:TestAPI:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Even if I call something not defined in my API the the build is successful (invoking `mvn test`), for an instance:

```
MainInterface.undefinedMethod(1,2,3,4,5);
```

Do I have the wrong use-case or is it because of misconfiguration of the POM?

Comment: Have you tried running with `-X`? The debug info from the plugin might help you determine what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @user944849 for the hint. The plugin printed its configuration to the debug log:

```
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-maven-plugin:1.13:check (default-cli)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <ignoreDependencies default-value="true"/>
  <localRepository>${localRepository}</localRepository>
  <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
  <project>${project}</project>
  <signature>
    <groupId>TestAPI</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestAPI</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </signature>
  <skip default-value="false">${animal.sniffer.skip}</skip>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
```

It turned out the dependencies were ignored since there were a setting `<ignoreDependencies default-value="true"/>`. Putting `<ignoreDependencies>true</ignoreDependencies>` into the plugin configuration in the pom resolved my issue.

I had also to reinstall the modified API-project into repository (skipping the build of the signatures) to avoid compilation errors.